# Why does LuaJIT's jit module appear as a string when loaded through require?

Tags: lua, luajit, sol3

I compiled a program on Linux using LuaJit 2.1 beta3.I loaded the profiler [as recommended in the docs](https://blast.hk/moonloader/luajit/ext_profiler.html), like so:

```
require("jit.p").start(options, output) 
require("jit.p").stop()
```

However, the module failed to open, citing a version mismatch. Upon inspection of the source code of the module I was loading (p), I noticed that the code checked the version like so:

```
-- Cache some library functions and objects.
local jit = require("jit")
assert(jit.version_num == 20100, "LuaJIT core/library version mismatch")
```

I also noticed that these two things are different:

```
print(require('jit')) -- This prints a string describing my LuaJIT version
print(jit)            -- This prints the table of the jit module
```

In other words, the LuaJIT profiler source code calls `require('jit')`, which returns a string, but is clearly expecting a table. If I change that line to comment out `jit = require('jit')`, it uses the preloaded jit package and everything works.

**Why do `jit` and `require('jit')` return different things? Is this a remnant of Sol3?**

Environment:

- Arch Linux
- luajit-2.1.0-beta3
- Binding to C++ with Sol3
- Repro here: https://github.com/spaderthomas/luajit-sol-repro

Comment: On a usual installation of LuaJIT `require"jit"==_G.jit` evaluates to `true`

Comment: So perhaps this has something to do with the Sol binding library.

Comment: Probably.  Try to post an issue there.